# Install Tcl tk binaries in Buildroot

Tags: tcl, buildroot

I want to have tclsh binary in my root file system generated by Buildroot.

In buildroot, we can (from menuconfig) go to Interpreter languages and scripting -> then choose tcl

But this will install tcl8.6 packages (opt0.4, http1.0). The tcl shell itself is not implemented in the generated file system.

Does anyone know how to enable tclsh in Buildroot

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will have to tell buildroot not to remove `tclsh` from your build, which, I guess, can be achieved by setting `BR2_PACKAGE_TCL_SHLIB_ONLY=n` after having run "make menuconfig"? This is just from skimming over the buildroot docs and https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/tree/package/tcl/tcl.mk#n51.

Comment: There is no Tk in buildroot, and would not make much sense, right?

Comment: @mrcalvin , yeah that was the solution, thanks for your help. I don't need tk actually. so finally I have tclsh is running

Comment: Glad that it helped. You might want to accept the corresponding answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to tell buildroot not to remove `tclsh` from your build. This can be achieved by setting `BR2_PACKAGE_TCL_SHLIB_ONLY=n` after having run `make menuconfig`.

See also https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/tree/package/tcl/tcl.mk#n51.